# Avoid executing external plugins' test cases

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, phpunit, laravel-5.4

**composer.json**

```
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.6.4",
        "laravel/framework": "5.4.*",
        "laravel/socialite": "^3.0",
        ...
        "chencha/share": "^5.2"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.4",
        "mockery/mockery": "0.9.*",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "~5.7"
    },
    ...
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
```

**phpunit.xml**

```
<phpunit backupGlobals="false"
         backupStaticAttributes="false"
         bootstrap="bootstrap/autoload.php"
         colors="true"
         convertErrorsToExceptions="true"
         convertNoticesToExceptions="true"
         convertWarningsToExceptions="true"
         processIsolation="false"
         stopOnFailure="false">
    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="Application Test Suite">
            <directory suffix="Test.php">./tests</directory>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>
    <filter>
        <whitelist processUncoveredFilesFromWhitelist="true">
            <directory suffix=".php">./app</directory>
        </whitelist>
    </filter>
    <php>
        <env name="APP_ENV" value="testing"/>
        <env name="CACHE_DRIVER" value="array"/>
        <env name="SESSION_DRIVER" value="array"/>
        <env name="QUEUE_DRIVER" value="sync"/>
    </php>
</phpunit>
```

When I run `phpunit` it gives me following error

`PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Orchestra\Testbench\TestCase' not found in /usr/lib/php5/voice/v1.5/vendor/chencha/share/tests/TestCase.php on line 3`

I can add `"orchestra/testbench": "~3.0"` under my `require-dev` which will solve the issue, But is there way I can run only my test cases without the plugins' test cases?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue. I didn't add the namesapce `use Tests\TestCase;` because of that it extends the external plugin's `TestCase` class. My bad, wasted lot of time on it.

Answer (score 0):

In standard configuration no tests from vendor directory are run. The phpunit.xml you showed seems quite normal, so you should make sure that you run tests in valid directory. You should be in the main application directory (looking at your error it should be `/usr/lib/php5/voice/v1.5/`) when you are running tests.

Comment: Hi yes I'm in the main application when I'm running the `phpunit`. Following is what inside the `/usr/lib/php5/voice/v1.5/vendor/chencha/share/tests/TestCase.php` file. `class TestCase extends Orchestra\Testbench\TestCase { }`. There is no test cases, just class declaration.

Comment: Hi found the issue. Thanks for this statement `In standard configuration no tests from vendor directory are run`, helps me to think differently. For a long time I'm debugging with the view its running the vendor test cases. :)